# Animating magnetic field lines on a circle

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate

So I want to create a changing vector as a function of theta and have it's origin stay on the path of a circle. The vector I want to plot is:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[
   Arrow[{{Cos[t*3.6 °], 
       Sin[t*3.6 °]}, {-Sin[t*3.6 °], 
       Cos[t*3.6 °]}}*{Sin[t*3.6 °], 
      2 Cos[t*3.6 °]}]]], {t, 0, 100, .25}]
```

I apologize that I'm not very good at mathematica; I'm pretty new and trying to learn. I know how to make a circle, but I don't know how to make the vector go in a circle. Any tips or ideas?

Btw, I did this in terms of time and wanted one full circle in 100 minutes, hence the t*3.6 ° part.

Updated code below:

```
Manipulate[
Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 8]}], 
Graphics[Arrow[{{Cos[θ*3.6 °], 
Sin[θ*3.6 °]}, {-Sin[θ*3.6 °], 
Cos[θ*3.6 °]}}*{Sin[θ*3.6 °], 
2 Cos[θ*3.6 °]}]], 
PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {θ, 0, 100, .11, 
Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

I want the origin of that vector to sit on the edge of the circle and in the *two* periods, make one full period around the circle such that it is pointing up at the top and bottom poles and down and the two equators. I was thinking of using offset, but it keeps giving me an error. What I have so far is this:

```
Manipulate[
Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 8]}], 
  Graphics[Arrow[{{Cos[t*3.6 °], 
    Sin[t*3.6 °]}, {-Sin[t*3.6 °], 
    Cos[t*3.6 °]}}*{Sin[t*3.6 °], 
    2 Cos[t*3.6 °]}, 
    Offset[{-8 Sin[t*3.6 °], 8 Cos[t*3.6 °]}, {0, 
    0}]], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]], {t, 0, 100, .11, 
    Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

I guess if it makes it more clear, I want the origin of the vector to line up with the dot at all times t in the following plot:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 8]}], 
   Graphics[Arrow[{{Cos[t*3.6 °], 
     Sin[t*3.6 °]}, {-Sin[t*3.6 °], 
     Cos[t*3.6 °]}}*{Sin[t*3.6 °], 
     2 Cos[t*3.6 °]}], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], 
   Graphics[Point[{-8 Sin[t*3.6 °], 
   8 Cos[t*3.6 °]}]]], {t, 0, 100, .1, 
Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

Does that make it more clear? I really really appreciate all of your help.

Comment: It is not clear enough what you are asking, you need to [edit] and clarify what you need, include example of desired output and some background. Somebody already spend time answering and was not what you needed as a consequence to the question been ambiguous.

Comment: does this give what you need: `Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 8], Black, 
   Arrow[8 {{- Sin[t*3.6 \[Degree]], 
       Cos[t*3.6 \[Degree]]}, {Sin[t*3.6 \[Degree]], - 
        Cos[t*3.6 \[Degree]]}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {t, 0, 100, .1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"}]`?

Answer (score 4):

I embellished a bit to show the circle as well, but that should be easy to remove if you like.  Also, note that since your vector points go as products of `Sin` and `Cos`, a full circle is achieved in only 180 degrees.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0.5}, .5]}],
  Graphics[
   Arrow[
    {{Cos[t 1.8 °], 
       Sin[t 1.8 °]}, {-Sin[t 1.8 °], 
       Cos[t 1.8 °]}}*{Sin[t 1.8 °], 
      2 Cos[t  1.8 °]}
    ]], PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-0.1, 2.1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
 , {{t, 0, Style["t", 25]}, 0, 100, .25, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Right, the multiplication is for rotating the vector to what a magnetic field line would look like if I went in a circle to the stationary perspective. That's what the Sin(~) + 2 Cos(~) is for. The point of my question was to plot that vector and have it go around a circle with radius R. As in the beginning point of that vector would be on a circle and as t -> 100 minutes, the vector would completely go around the circle while pointing in the proper orientation. Sorry if I was not clear. I really appreciate your help though!

Comment: Thanks for that, that helps a bit, but still not exactly what I'm looking for. The reason I want it to go 2 cycles is because this is a magnetic field circling earth, so it should have two periods within one full orbit. I've modified what you've given me to show more exactly what I want.

Comment: I really appreciate all of your help, but the thing I've been having the most trouble with is, I guess, offsetting the origin of the vector to an arbritary point. Any ideas on that? Sorry I've been so unclear.